# how call function jquery inside url ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to be able to call a function from the "url" region instead of having to place my code in that region.

Here is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "addpost()",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
  $(xml).find('weather').each(function () {
     // Load New Data
     ...
});
},
  error: function (xml) {
    alert("Unrecognized Region. Please try again.");
  }
}); 
function addpost()
{
  ///this my code
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `addPost()` will return a URL string that you want to use in your AJAX call?

Comment: What your addpost function will return, URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to a variable outside the `AJAX` call and then place that variable as the url

```
var setUrl = AddPost();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: setUrl,
    // do the things
});
```

I did some more researching, and it seems you can also do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: function (){
            AddPost()
         },
    data: data.
    // do things
}
```

Comment: You can directly call the function addPost() if it is returning URL, no need to get in variable separately.

Comment: I am a fan of this variable approach. I think it makes it more readable.

Comment: I'm agree but, how your approach can help to solve this issue?

Comment: the resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/null

Comment: @saeed3164 that looks like there is something wrong with your path or the return from AddPost().. I'm guessing you implemented this, then, and therefor worked for what you originally asked?

Comment: @saeed3164 how you getting URL inside you function is there another Ajax call?  print that URL to your console and verify that, is it valid URL?

Comment: @saeed3164 did this answer your original, posted question?

Comment: Requested URL: /Home/function (){ AddPost() }

Comment: Go with the first option I have in my answer. In Chrome Dev Tools, look at what the variable `setUrl` is set to before it enters your `AJAX` call.. It should be /Controller/Function/Data

Answer (score 0):

if your function return the url you can just ball it before the ajax request

```
var ajaxUrl = addpost();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: ajaxUrl,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
  $(xml).find('weather').each(function () {
     // Load New Data
     ...
});
},
  error: function (xml) {
    alert("Unrecognized Region. Please try again.");
  }
}); 
function addpost()
{
  ///this my code
}
```

Comment: the resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/null

Comment: @saeed3164 where is the addPost() function ? you should check if you receive the url from it. and if it's a valid url. Can you show me code ?